# How to use Mathematica to calculate number of spanning tree?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

As the title,The graph `g` is:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 6}, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"]
```

[image]

My reference book just give the answer is `81`. But how to use  *Mathematica* to calculate it? I couldn't find related built-in functions. Anybody can try it?

Comment: I would argue that this is really a math question and not a Mathematica one.  See here why: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpanningTree.html

Comment: @Szabolcs It's seem the `NumberOfSpanningTrees` is what I want.Thanks for your link.Do you think I should close this question?

Comment: No, I don't think you have to, I just pointed out that IMO the key is being aware of the math (and not looking for a builtin function).  You could write an answer that calculates it *without* this Combinatorica function, based on one of the two formulae in the MathWorld article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a large(r) *connected graph*, an approach using [Kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) is much faster and uses less memory than `TuttePolynomial`.  We generate the *Laplacian matrix* for the graph (*Mathematica* calls this `KirchhoffMatrix`), drop one row and one column from the `KirchhoffMatrix` and calculate the Determinant of the adjusted matrix.

```
rand = RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[Table[3, {30}]]]

AbsoluteTiming[TuttePolynomial[rand, {1, 1}]]

AbsoluteTiming[kirk = KirchhoffMatrix[rand]; 
               spans = Det[kirk[[1 ;; -2, 1 ;; -2]]]]

(* Out *)
{30.262097, 12181794623}
{0.005720, 12181794623}
```

Answer (score 7):

From the Properties and Relations section of `TuttePolynomial` (thanks to Szabolcs):

> `TuttePolynomial[g,{1,1}]` counts the number of spanning trees in the graph:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= TuttePolynomial[GridGraph[{2, 3}], {1, 1}]
>
> Out[1]= 15
> ```

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 6}, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"]

TuttePolynomial[g, {1, 1}]
```

$\ $ `81`

Answer (score 2):

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) 0.3.98 or later, you can use

```
IGSpanningTreeCount[g]
```

It uses Kirchhoff's theorem, as in [the answer by PlaysDice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102205/12).

It works with directed graphs and non-simple graphs. To make this possible, the standard output of [`KirchhoffMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KirchhoffMatrix.html) cannot be used (I would argue that in a sense what `KirchhoffMatrix` returns is not correct, though one can argue about definitions).  For this reason, `IGKirchhoffMatrix` is also provided.